# ¿Cómo enviar notificaciones push del navegador cuando la pestaña o el navegador están cerrados en Django?

Tags: django, push-notification

Quiero implementar notificaciones push en mi proyecto con django.

Quiero mostrar las notificaciones incluso cuando el navegador y la pestaña están cerrados, he visto que esto es implementado por Facebook o telegrama web.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Gracias a todos